# Unhandled rejection (Type Error): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to develop an application using react js, this error is coming.

The line where this error occurs is:

```
else{
 history.push({
         pathname:"/fullpage-error",
         state:{details:e.response.data.errors[0]}      //this is the main line of error
         });
}
}
};
export default globalAPIFunction;
```

Comment: Seems like response is undefined. Use console.log(‘response’, e.response) to see the output of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of variable "e" at the line where the error occurs?

The variable e doesn't have the property "response"(It will be undefined), So it is not able to access the "data" property of undefined.

You can add a null pointer check before your statement if the variable e is a dynamic variable which you receiving from an API service or any third-party application

```
else{
if(e.response)
 history.push({
         pathname:"/fullpage-error",
         state:{details:e.response.data.errors[0]}      //this is the main line of error
         });
}
}
};
export default globalAPIFunction;
```

Read more about
"Type Error": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing error because the 'e' object is not set yet.
you need to check first if it is defined or not do like this

```
else{
 history.push({
         pathname:"/fullpage-error",
         state:{details:e.response ? e.response.data.errors[0] : ''}      //this is the main line of error
         });
}
}
};
export default globalAPIFunction;
```